# Kotlin inline value class creates "cannot find symbol" when called in java

Tags: java, kotlin, inline, value-class

I have the following class in kotlin:

```
@JvmInline
value class ItemId(val value: String)

data class Item(
     var id: ItemId? = null
)
```

However if I ever call `Item.getId()` from a java class it will give me a `cannot find symbol` error while compiling.

From my understanding during compilation ([according to this docs page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html#mangling)), the value class should be converted into a String during compilation, so I don't understand why or how getId() does not exist according to the java side.

Whenever the Item constructor is called, a similar error occurs: `Item(...) has private access in ...`

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: That conversion is a *Kotlin compiler* feature. You cannot expect it to work from Java code.

Comment: When I run javap on the resultant classfile, the only constructors are `public foo.Item(java.lang.String, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker);` and `public foo.Item(java.lang.String, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker);`. The `getId` gets some gibberish appended: `public final java.lang.String getId-yVWcZVQ();`. I guess Jorn is right. This is just incompatible with Java.

Comment: @Jorn but during the kotlin compilation it gets converted into standard JVM and that can be used by the java compiler right? We have data classes and those work just fine, the documentation even says that it should convert into a standard string type during kotlin compilation and that that can be called through java (read the documentation I linked in the question)

Comment: @Michael what's strange to me is that the documentation I linked specifically mentions calling a method with an inline class in java, a nearly exactly identical case

Comment: The documentation you linked has a section on [mangling](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html#mangling) which describes exactly what you're experiencing. Your `getId` method is mangled exactly as documented. That's why you can't use it from Java.

Comment: @k314159 but in that example there are two methods where the generated method would result in the same output right? In the example below under the "calling from java" they are making a direct call. I don't see how there is a signature clash in this case, as well as others

Comment: If you want to call it from Java, you need to add `@JvmName` as that section says.

Comment: @k314159 looking at it again it does indeed look like I misunderstood what the section was referring to. I got confused by the docs combining both a clash and jvmname within the same example made me think that mangling was only necessary when there was a clash, while that's not the case